# Create a Django model with referencing Models in Manager class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.5 and Python 2.7 and these example models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Showroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

**How would I go about creating a "Company" with a default "Showroom".** I know I could do this in the view, eg.

```
company = models.Company(name=name, email=email)
company.save()
showroom = models.Showroom(name=name, company=company)
showroom.save()
```

and I tried using a Manager like:

```
class CompanyManager(models.Manager):
    def create_company(self, name, email):
        company = self.create(name=name, email=email)
        company.save() # <-- DONT LIKE THIS LINE
        user = User.objects.create_user(name, email, 'generated')
        showroom = Showroom(name=name, company=company)
        showroom.save()
        return company
```

Can I use the unsaved company to create my showroom? If not, I need to save it, but this is breaking the convention that the manager returns an unsaved instance (or am I wrong?).

Can anybody recommend a strategy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would I go about creating a "Company" with a default "Showroom?

Override the save method of model Company or register a post save signal on model Company.

Can I use the unsaved company to create my showroom?

No.

Updated:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.showroom__set.create(name=self.name)
```

Updated by Berdus:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_first_save = self.pk is None
    super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_first_save:
        self.showroom_set.create(name=self.name)
```

Note the self argument in save and the single underscore on showroom_set.

Comment: Thanks, after minor tweaks this solution works... Updated the answer with the code I use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I think of it.

setting.py

```
DEFAULT_SHOWROOM_NAME = 'blah'
```

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.showroom__set.all():
             self.showroom__set.create(name=DEFAULT_SHOWROOM_NAME)
```

Comment: I updated my answer, You don't need to do extra query (self.showroom__set.all())